# Using variable in different file

Tags: java, variables, import

I have two separate programs in java, and I have saved them in two different files. I want to use a variable (which is in the first program) in the second program.

How to do this?

Comment: First, please put some effort in your question and don't use abbreviations like "b". Second, try and show us a short example of your files and/or add a bit more of a description. Are those "programs" designed to run independently? Are those just 2 classes? Do you know how to import other classes and how to put them on the class path?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to the second method

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "want to use a variable in another program".  How are you defining your variables?  The two "programs" must be two separate classes, so you'll be defining a variable as a class member, most likely.  So, in you first class, you could have something like

```
public class ClassA {
    public int variable;
    ...
}
```

and then in your second class you coul access it like so:

```
public class ClassB {
    public ClassB() {
        int var = new ClassA().variable;
    }
}
```

Depending on how you define that variable (public/private/protected and static/instance), the way to access it would be different.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume a few things here. The first assumption is that you are trying to access a variable in a different class and the second assumption is that those classes are in the same package most likely the default package. So to access a variable in class A from class B you need to instantiate class A.

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA{
    public int mMyInt = 10; 
}
```

ClassB.java

```
public class ClassB{
    public ClassB(){
        ClassA myClass = new ClassA();
        System.out.println(myClass.mMyInt);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ClassB app = new ClassB();
    }   
}
```

I hope this helps.